# Javascript button for browser extension does not have onclick function after declaring it using javascript

Tags: javascript, browser-extension

I'm writing a browser extension (next episode button for a video player) and the button I added using pure JS does not have the onclick function declared. onmouseover and on mouseout work fine.

[Code snippet for issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i0LSM.png)

[Output from browser logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RtfnI.png)

[Button does not have trigger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MbgB7.png)

Thanks for any help that can be provided.

edit: Here is the code as text (someone suggested it)

```
function next(){
    var url_arr = window.location.pathname.split("/");
    var match = url_arr[3].match(/[0-9]+$/)[0];
    var new_num = (1+parseInt(url_arr[3].match(/[1-9]+$/))).toString();
    while (new_num.length < match.length)
        {
            new_num = "0" + new_num;
         }
     var new_location = window.location.href.replace(/[0-9]+$/,new_num);
     window.location.href = new_location
}

console.log(document.getElementsByClassName('control-bar_container'));
console.log(document.getElementsByClassName('control-bar_container').item(0));
var vid_bar = document.getElementsByClassName('control-bar_container')[0];
var btn = document.createElement('button');
console.log(vid_bar);
console.log(btn);
var next_button = vid_bar.appendChild(btn);
next_button.id = "next-button";
next_button.onclick = next;
console.log(next);
console.log(next_button.onclick);
```

Comment: Add code as text

Comment: I just done it now. Should I remove the code images on there or leave them since they're already up?